# Sample codes for facial gesture recognition with OpenCV (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, gesture-recognition

I would need actual C++ code examples on how to create a code deciphering facial gestures (with OpenCV). Google used to be my friend, but it betrayed me by showing just tutorials on the question, while I would need to see some working code for inspiration.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Today I came across this when I was playing with our friend (Even he is my friend). Check if this helps http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/opengazer/

Comment: Thank you, @user2727765 It seems that Google is more a friend of yours than mine. ;)